ssh-keyscan to get host key of SFTP server through an authenticated proxy
I want to get the host key of a SFTP server.
But, I have an authenticated proxy between me and the SFTP server. I have the following details about the proxy: proxy_host, proxy_port, proxy_user and proxy_password.
How do I use ssh-keyscan / ssh to go past the authenticated proxy?
I have openssh-client and netcat installed in my oracle linux 8 VM.
I don't want to use tools like proxytunnel or corkscrew.

Since you mention proxytunnel and corkscrew, it sounds like it is an HTTP 'CONNECT' proxy.
OpenSSH does not support using any kind of proxy natively, neither HTTP CONNECT nor otherwise; it relies on some kind of external tool (with ProxyCommand).
Some nc implementations have HTTP proxy support built-in, e.g. openbsd-netcat has the -x option for that:
ssh -o ProxyCommand="nc -x proxy_host:proxy_port -P proxy_user %h %p"

If you have a different nc, you'll need to write a shell script that manually sends the CONNECT request, which looks like:
CONNECT real_host:real_port HTTP/1.1
Proxy-Authorization: <scheme> <base64data>
<blank line>

For Basic auth, the data is Base64 encoded proxy_user:proxy_pass.
The script might then look like:
#!/bin/sh
real_host=$1
real_port=$2
auth_data=$(echo -n "$proxy_user:$proxy_pass" | base64)
(echo "CONNECT $real_host:$real_port HTTP/1.1";
 echo "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth_data";
 echo "";
 stdbuf -i0 -o0 cat) | nc $proxy_host $proxy_port

and the script would be invoked as ssh -o ProxyCommand="~/myscript %h %p".
(This is exactly what proxytunnel does, so... in order to SSH through an HTTP proxy, you will unavoidably use "a tool like proxytunnel or corkscrew".)
ssh-keyscan does not support ProxyCommand, but you can achieve a similar result by running ssh (with different -o HostKeyAlgorithms=) and letting it save keys into your known_hosts.

I went with the script that you provided and it worked. Thanks for the detailed answer, helped me quite a lot!
